# How to select dates based on condition on another row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have the following data, where I want to print a few rows depending on some other condition on other columns:

[image]

The condition is that, if (role = xx or role = yy) and status = Approved, then we need to pick up the max(Start_Date) from both of the rows.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please, do not post images, instead edit your question to post the data as formatted text + your attempt + the expected results

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: What is your expected sample output?

Comment: And what about the rest of the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The condition is that, if (role = xx or role = yy) and status = Approved, then we need to pick up the max(Start_Date) from both of the rows.

I assume that this refers to per `id` and thatyou want to filter out the other rows.  A relatively simple method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.role in ('xx', 'yy') and
      t.status = 'Approved' and
      t.start_date = (select max(t2.start_date)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.id = t.id and
                            t2.role in ('xx', 'yy') and
                            t2.status = 'Approved'
                     );
```

You can also phrase this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by start_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where t.role in ('xx', 'yy') and
            t.status = 'Approved' 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Both of these can be readily modified to choose the other rows, but that is not how I interpret the question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        case when role in ('xx', 'yy') and status = 'Approved'
            then row_number() over(partition by id order by start_date desc)
            else 1
        end rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The idea is to to rank records that satisfy a set of particular conditions, and to assign a default rank to all other records. Then this custom rank can be used for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
select 
case when (role='xx' or role='yy') and status ='approved'
then max([date])
else [date]
end as 'your column name'

 from [yourtable]  
 group by role,status ,[date]
```